# Comments and Attachments UX

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design, layout, interface, files

I'm trying to find examples of sites which have the ability to make a comment and add multiple attachments to said comment. So far, the only example I have found of this is teamgantt.com which is kind of what I'm looking for. Does anyone have any other examples of sites that do this or have any ideas about it? Specifically, I'm looking for what might happen when there are a number of attachments - is there a scroll function or something else? - and whether or not there should be thumbnail images of the attachments. Thanks. [image: Teamgantt Image]

Answer (score 1):

In development, usually, there's no specified limit to the number of attachments which make up that 5MB (or 2MB/ 20MB, this value differ from server to server).

If the files have a small size, the number can be pretty big. I don't recommend scroll, I think it is a better idea to group the files in columns, using the grid you have in the project.

If you want to limit the number, you can display a message to let the user know you have this limitation “Please don't attach too many files at once. Try reducing the number of files being attached.”

Answer (score 1):

My thoughts for the requirement is as follows:

Showing limited text and attachments provides page real estate for other segments (comments and attachments) and the user can see more data without having to scroll down.

Key points about the wireframe (attached below), most of the design is self-explanatory.
User can, click on:

- “Expand All” to reveal all the sections (all comments and attachments) – Page level
- “Expand” to reveal only one section (comments and attachment panel) – Segment level
- “Show More” to reveal comments or attachments. But, if you are limiting the comments to certain character length, you can avoid “Show More / Show Less” for text and get rid of the “Expand” at each segment level to minimize the number of clicks.

You have to take care of: The users find difficulty in reading a long width text (based on the device width) and there are chances of jumping between the lines of text, so the length (width) should be as advised by research.

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much. That's kind of the thing I'm looking for. Just trying to find a few different examples and come up with the simplest design.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great example - you are using it right now. StackOverflow is a. Great example how attachments can work. You would probably want to add some wysiwyg editor to your comments so that people can comfortable call a popup with the for to upload their attachments.

Answer (score 0):

I should also point out that the idea here is to fit the comment and attachments into a space that doesn't change in size.